# Using jQuery .click() method makes page jump to top, and returning false doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have a few canvas elements and their appropriate jQuery:

```
$( "#myCanvas" ).click(function() {
  $( "#myHistogram" ).fadeToggle( 0 );
  $("#myCanvas").fadeToggle( 0 );
});
$( "#myHistogram" ).click(function() {
  $( "#myHistogram" ).fadeToggle( 0 );
  $("#myCanvas").fadeToggle( 0 );
});
$( "#stdDevCanvas" ).click(function() {
  $( "#stdDevCanvas" ).fadeToggle( 0 );
  $("#stdDevHistogram").fadeToggle( 0 );
});
$( "#stdDevHistogram" ).click(function() {
  $( "#stdDevCanvas" ).fadeToggle( 0 );
  $("#stdDevHistogram").fadeToggle( 0 );
});
```

Basically you can just toggle between a time chart and a histogram. When I click however, it sends me to the top of the page. I tried:

```
$( "#myCanvas" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $( "#myHistogram" ).fadeToggle( 0 );
  $("#myCanvas").fadeToggle( 0 );
});
```

And had no success. What is causing the page jump? I've never dealt with this before.

Here's a live page:

http://lavancier.com/brockCharts/aa-research-data.php

Thanks!

EDIT: Upon further inspection, this problem only happens when both times are set to zero. If I change them to 1, it doesn't scroll to the top automatically.

I solved it by getting rid of the ( 0 ).

This works:

```
$( "#myCanvas" ).click(function() {
  $("#myCanvas").hide( );
  $( "#myHistogram" ).show( );
});
$( "#myHistogram" ).click(function() {
  $( "#myHistogram" ).hide( );
  $("#myCanvas").show( );
});
$( "#stdDevCanvas" ).click(function() {
  $("#stdDevCanvas").hide( );
  $( "#stdDevHistogram" ).show( );
});
$( "#stdDevHistogram" ).click(function() {
  $( "#stdDevHistogram" ).hide( );
  $("#stdDevCanvas").show( );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because of fading order. The moment you click on a canvas, it fades out leaving a gap then the next canvas is faded in, however the browser sees this gap and scrolls the document to the top because there is no more content below. Of course this happens extremely fast and it's only programatically noticeable.

You can fix this by changing the order

```
$("#myCanvas").click(function () {
    $("#myHistogram").fadeToggle(0);
    $("#myCanvas").fadeToggle(0);
});
$("#myHistogram").click(function () {
    $("#myCanvas").fadeToggle(0);
    $("#myHistogram").fadeToggle(0);
});
$("#stdDevCanvas").click(function (e) {
    $("#stdDevHistogram").fadeToggle(0);
    $("#stdDevCanvas").fadeToggle(0);
});
$("#stdDevHistogram").click(function (e) {
    $("#stdDevCanvas").fadeToggle(0);
    $("#stdDevHistogram").fadeToggle(0);
});
```

Note how the next canvas fades in first then the clicked on fades out, this prevents from the element of leaving a 0 height in the body.